# Typescript running same method on diffrent object types

Tags: typescript

I want to create function that accepts `obj` and `value` as arguments and runs objects method `add` with passed value. Unfortunetly obeject can be either typeof `A` or `B`. Depending on object type method `add` accepts `string` or `number`. How can i achive that?

```js
class A {
  add(a: number) {
    return 10 + a
  }
}

class B {
  add(a: string) {
    return 'ten' + a
  }
}
```

I tried doing something like that but typescript lints it (and I understand that).

```js
const runObejctMethod = (obj: A | B, value: string | number) => {
    obj.add(value)
}
```

error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [generically constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) function signature to accept an object whose `add` method is compatible with the constraint.

You can also define the compatibility of the constraint from specific classes that you choose by using a type utility.

I've explained this more in the comments in the code below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-odFDlNtPS1W3iw57AwGAxElXgfLZgOfPtPsYoofApvyLSbreeySoy5DdpqhzHP2OjnFE5wACKDkao73HO-IALS4Xh+EEQRWHQAAqhAYBWGQIS-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-XTMDuNUvgZR4ocK0KSvdCrau1JrBW+8D7sm2bb0U59A1nkTqM5CbQsi9jWv3aD6cWx9VM27n2S5KkhezYtq3rZtQA)

```ts
class A {
  add (value: number): number {
    return 10 + value;
  }
}

class B {
  add (value: string): string {
    return 'ten' + value;
  }
}

class C {
  add (value: { num: number }): { num: number } {
    return { num: 10 + value.num };
  }
}

function runObejctMethod <T extends Parameters<(A | B)['add']>[0]>(
  obj: { add: (value: T) => T },
  value: T,
): void {
  const result = obj.add(value);
  console.log(result);
}

// The constraint expression above "Parameters<(A | B)['add']>[0]" means:
// "a union of the type of the first parameter of A.add or B.add",
// so — in this case — it means "string | number":
type Constraint = Parameters<(A | B)['add']>[0];
   //^? type Constraint = string | number

// You could add more compatible classes to the union
// to extend the accepted types in the constraint,
// for example: Parameters<(A | B | C | D)['add']>[0]

// --------------------

// Usage:

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const c = new C();

// Ok:
runObejctMethod(a, 1); //=> Logs: 11
runObejctMethod(b, ' thousand'); //=> Logs: "ten thousand"

// Not ok (as expected):
runObejctMethod(a, ' thousand'); /*
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345) */

runObejctMethod(b, 1); /*
                   ~
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345) */

runObejctMethod(c, { num: 1 }); /*
                ~
Argument of type 'C' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ add: (value: string | number) => string | number; }'.
  Types of property 'add' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: { num: number; }) => number' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number) => string | number'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type '{ num: number; }'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ num: number; }'.(2345) */
```

---

`c` is not a compatible object type, but if you had included it in the original constraint, it would be allowed:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=38#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pgCbugCgG5hAFcBTALmgDtCBbAI2ICcBKcquxxFVaB4gF0IMK0AIwAGaAGpo+IsQDcXAL5IVSUJBgAhTqgxY8BEuQh8GASwoBzFtFMXru7rwFDoAcj7EK7qTKMKyqpI6uBQ0ADCTvo4ssaIlDSsNPQM0Eq2CInUyexpSk6oLoLCWWzk4n5xxAB0bOmKqCpqAGaEFMB85gD2wgztAPL0AFadALL8ABbdWAA8ACrQxAAeXhToMAAKYAxg1PyMELPY8AA+0DrnEUwA2u767gC6AHw3Yi-YXAD0X9x--wDAUDgSCAHrfX4gqHQ7hRcwwCjdADu0EsoEI6GIWEs0D4k2I0HaPQoXG6tGG5Cy+nIhjk5HmTGgAF5ntBFkoADRcar0rm2XDdcxYZCoYC9Uw8YgQQggPjM6Bk4Y1fS0khMRrQMUUCDdEC1EDdKzYXjS2Xq4LqcVy4DyijEFERbDm-oUIbEUZ8CZ4mbYYAchLlUTpdXQH7QAYAayQQA)

```ts
class C {
  add (value: { num: number }): { num: number } {
    return { num: 10 + value.num };
  }
}

function runObejctMethod <T extends Parameters<(A | B | C)['add']>[0]>(
  //                                                    ^
  //                                     C is now included in the union
  obj: { add: (value: T) => T },
  value: T,
): void {
  const result = obj.add(value);
  console.log(result);
}

const c = new C();
runObejctMethod(c, { num: 1 }); // Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using type guards to determine the type of the object and then call the correct method. You can do this by checking the type of the object with the `typeof` operator, or by checking for the existence of a specific property on the object.

Here's an example using the `typeof` operator:

```
const runObejctMethod = (obj: A | B, value: string | number) => {
  if (typeof obj === 'A') {
    obj.add(value as number);
  } else {
    obj.add(value as string);
  }
}
```

In this example, we use the `typeof` operator to check the type of `obj`. If it's an instance of `A`, we call the `add` method with a value that has been explicitly typed as a number using the `as` keyword. Otherwise, we call the `add` method with a value that has been explicitly typed as a string.

You can also use a type guard by checking for the existence of a specific property on the object. For example, you could add a property called `isA` to the `A` class and use it in a type guard like this:

```
class A {
  isA = true;
  add(a: number) {
    return 10 + a
  }
}

class B {
  add(a: string) {
    return 'ten' + a
  }
}

const runObejctMethod = (obj: A | B, value: string | number) => {
  if (obj.isA) {
    obj.add(value as number);
  } else {
    obj.add(value as string);
  }
}
```

In this example, we check for the existence of the `isA` property on the `obj` object. If it exists, we know that `obj` is an instance of `A`, and we call the `add` method with a value that has been explicitly typed as a `number`. If the `isA` property doesn't exist, we know that `obj` is an instance of `B`, and we call the add method with a value that has been explicitly typed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You may use generics

```
const runObejctMethod2 = <C extends {add(v: any): any}>(obj: C, value: Parameters<C['add']>[0]) => {
    obj.add(value)
}
```

There are other methods (like overloaning), but they may require casting with `as` or long generics